# Changing the selected value of <select> element many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can set the selected value no problem -- there's lots of answers for that problem already on Stack-Overflow.

My question is how could I continue to *CHANGE* the selected value?

I first thought I'd just remove the "selected" attribute off of the options, then set the targeted option's "selected" attribute back on.

And it worked!!

--- for a cycle.

It would appear you can only change the selected value 'x' amount of times before it just gets stuck on the first option and does not respond to changes.

```js
$('#btn_25').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#my_selector option').attr('selected', false);
    $('#my_selector option[value=' + 25 + ']').attr('selected', true);
});

$('#btn_50').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#my_selector option').attr('selected', false);
    $('#my_selector option[value=' + 50 + ']').attr('selected', true);
});

$('#btn_100').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#my_selector option').attr('selected', false);
    $('#my_selector option[value=' + 100 + ']').attr('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_selector">
    <option value="25">Twenty Five</option>
    <option value="50">Fifty</option>
    <option value="100">One Hundred</option>
</select>

<button id="btn_25">25</button>
<button id="btn_50">50</button>
<button id="btn_100">100</button>
```

If you click the buttons left-to-right twice through, you'll find yourself stuck at value 25. At least, I do.

My question is --- is this a problem with my code? With JQuery (I doubt that VERY much)? With FireFox (version 41.0.1)?

If the problem is with my code -- what needs changing to allow continuous setting of the select-element's value?

Comment: Why not use `val(25/50/100)`?

Comment: `$('#my_selector option').attr('selected', false);` For every place you use `.attr`, change to `.prop` would work. However,  use `.val` to set the select's value would be better.

Comment: I guess the answers I found on Stack Overflow were out of date! VERY cool that it's so easy to change! 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to set `select` value. Also you should use a common class to bind event, the value which needs to set can be store in custom `data-*` prefix attributes, which can be fetched using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#my_selector').val($(this).data('value'));
  }); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my_selector">
  <option value="25">Twenty Five</option>
  <option value="50">Fifty</option>
  <option value="100">One Hundred</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn" data-value="25">25</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-value="50">50</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" data-value="100">100</button>
```

Comment: Well, shoot! -- thank you very much, Satpal! Especially for the extra advice there, too -- brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('#btn_25').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#my_selector').val('25');
});

$('#btn_50').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#my_selector').val('50');
});

$('#btn_100').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#my_selector').val('100');
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/92euh88o/